# Вопрос по поводу api авторизации vk.com

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Если я авторизируюсь через vk api на сайте, то получаю нужные данные от сервера vk и использую их для идентификации пользователя, вот интересно а если я авторизировался по этой системе то будет ли на сайте vk.com видно что я в онлайн?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, для этого можете воспользоваться методом [setOnline](http://vk.com/dev/account.setOnline), который пометит аккаунт online на 15 минут.

Comment: Добавлю: «визит» через API оставит следы в *Настройки* - [*Безопасность*](https://vk.com/settings?act=security) - *История активности*: там будет название приложения и ip адрес. Разумеется, эта информация видна только владельцу аккаунта.